# Testing if any element of a class has HTML

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
var ShowPreview = false;
    
$('#SomeID').find('.SomeClass').each(function () {
    
    if ($(this).html().length) {
    
        ShowPreview = true;
    }
});
```

Basically, I'm looping through elements and if one has HTML in it then I'm setting a boolean to true. Is there a better more concise way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var showPreview = $('#SomeID .SomeClass').contents().length > 0;
```

Comment: This doesn't account for text nodes. `<div class="SomeClass">foo</div>` would be considered as empty. You can use `.contents()` instead of `.children()`.

Comment: looking for epic cases.:) let's think

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
var ShowPreview = $('#SomeID .SomeClass:not(:empty)').length > 0;
```

http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/
http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Or

```
var ShowPreview = $('#SomeID .SomeClass').contents().length > 0;
```

http://api.jquery.com/contents/

Comment: `:empty` will not trigger if an element has a `whitespace`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: `$(this).html().length` won't either, which is what the OP uses currently.

Comment: @FelixKling exactly, just making sure OP is strictly interested in *content* or actual HTML child elements.

Answer (score 2):

```
var ShowPreview = $('#SomeID .SomeClass').filter(function () {
    return $.trim(this.innerHTML) !== "";
}).length > 0;
```

On a side note, I would recommend you dont capitalize `ShowPreview` as that is a convention in javascript for a class. Also html classes and ids should generally be lower case (ie `some-class`.